# Why am I getting this error while installing pygame in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygame, pycharm

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Eli Heist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fjf50xi9\pygame\`

this is the full process

```
(venv) C:\Users\Eli Heist\PycharmProjects\Space Invaders Ultimate>pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/b8/06e02c7cca7aec915839927a9aa19f749ac17a3d2bb2610b945d2de0aa96/pygame-2.0.1.tar.gz (5.5MB)

    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.5MB 996kB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Eli Heist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fjf50xi9\pygame\setup.py", line 318, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\Eli Heist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fjf50xi9\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 221, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\Eli Heist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fjf50xi9\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 574, in main
        return setup_prebuilt_sdl2(prebuilt_dir)
      File "C:\Users\Eli Heist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fjf50xi9\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 499, in setup_prebuilt_sdl2
        DEPS.configure()
      File "C:\Users\Eli Heist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fjf50xi9\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 336, in configure
        from . import vstools
      File "C:\Users\Eli Heist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fjf50xi9\pygame\buildconfig\vstools.py", line 11, in <module>
        compiler.initialize()
      File "C:\Users\Eli Heist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 372, in initialize
        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
      File "C:\Users\Eli Heist\PycharmProjects\Space Invaders Ultimate\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line
147, in msvc9_query_vcvarsall
      File "C:\Users\Eli Heist\PycharmProjects\Space Invaders Ultimate\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line
1227, in return_env
      File "C:\Users\Eli Heist\PycharmProjects\Space Invaders Ultimate\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line
876, in VCIncludes
      File "C:\Users\Eli Heist\PycharmProjects\Space Invaders Ultimate\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg\setuptools\msvc.py", line
555, in VCInstallDir
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.2 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualst
udio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
    Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.14-VC.zip 48d5dcd4a445410301f5575219cffb6de654edb8
    Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.14-VC.zip:
    Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip 137f86474691f4e12e76e07d58d5920c8d844d5b
    Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip:
    Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip 1436df41ebc47ac36e02ec9bda5699e80ff9bd27
    Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip:
    Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip 9097148f4529cf19f805ccd007618dec280f0ecc
    Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip:
    Downloading... https://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsr9d.zip ed10aa2b5a0fcfe74f8a6f7611aeb346b06a1f99
    Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\jpegsr9d.zip:
    Downloading... https://pygame.org/ftp/prebuilt-x64-pygame-1.9.2-20150922.zip 3a5af3427b3aa13a0aaf5c4cb08daaed341613ed
    Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\prebuilt-x64-pygame-1.9.2-20150922.zip:
    copying into .\prebuilt-x64
    Path for SDL: prebuilt-x64\SDL2-2.0.14
    ...Library directory for SDL: prebuilt-x64/SDL2-2.0.14/lib/x64
    ...Include directory for SDL: prebuilt-x64/SDL2-2.0.14/include
    Path for FONT: prebuilt-x64\SDL2_ttf-2.0.15
    ...Library directory for FONT: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15/lib/x64
    ...Include directory for FONT: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15/include
    Path for IMAGE: prebuilt-x64\SDL2_image-2.0.5
    ...Library directory for IMAGE: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/lib/x64
    ...Include directory for IMAGE: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/include
    Path for MIXER: prebuilt-x64\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4
    ...Library directory for MIXER: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/lib/x64
    ...Include directory for MIXER: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/include
    Path for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x64
    ...Library directory for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x64/lib
    ...Include directory for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x64/include
    DLL for SDL2: prebuilt-x64/SDL2-2.0.14/lib/x64/SDL2.dll
    DLL for SDL2_ttf: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15/lib/x64/SDL2_ttf.dll
    DLL for SDL2_image: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/lib/x64/SDL2_image.dll
    DLL for SDL2_mixer: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/lib/x64/SDL2_mixer.dll
    DLL for portmidi: prebuilt-x64/lib/portmidi.dll
    Path for FREETYPE not found.
    ...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x64.
    Path for PNG not found.
    ...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x64.
    Path for JPEG not found.
    ...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x64.
    DLL for freetype: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15/lib/x64/libfreetype-6.dll

    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---


    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Eli Heist\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fjf50xi9\pygame\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this error because `pip` is attempting to compile the complete [SDL library](https://www.libsdl.org/) for pygame, and your machine is missing the build requirements to do so. This is in your error message:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.2 is required
```

Luckily, pygame offers pre-compiled binaries for most operating systems so you don't have to compile yourself. They are distributed as [Python wheels](https://pythonwheels.com/). All you should have to do to access the pre-compiled version is install `wheel`:

```
C:\>pip install wheel
C:\>pip install pygame
```

Answer (score 2):

Today my friends met the same questions.
It seems that pygame has been not suit to python3.11.0,becase I can install it by python 3.10.7 but not by python 3.11.0.So you can use python3.10.7 instead of python3.11.0 to solve this quesiton.

Comment: This is the problem. Pygame DOES NOT run on Python 3.11 yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this problem can be solved but I will try to help.

Try the following things:

1. Don't install it for that specific project. Try to just go to cmd and install it for your whole python env.
2. Make sure python is properly installed in the PATH variable.
3. Try to use `py -m pip install -U pygame --user` instead. If that doesn't work, try `python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user`.

If you are using python 3.8 and/or none of the above methods work, you have two options: either revert to python 3.7 or wait for pygame to get updated. Pygame is known to function improperly in python 3.8. I had faced the same issue and I solved it by switching to python 3.7 for pygame projects and the latest version for other python projects.